# Website HTML Artefact

Tags: html, css

i am working on a website and while making my design i reached a point where i had a problem where an artefact apeared on one of my sections.

Here is the artefact : [image]

I have no clue about where the second Friend List comes from. If someone can help me, since i can't use the ctrl + shift + c to know from where it comes from.
It's like it just appeared there and i have no clue why it does that behaviour.

Thanks for your responses in advance!

Comment: Drill down inside that div on the elements tab. You can't always highlight it with Ctrl+Shift+C.

Comment: Actually i can't highlight it, that's the actual real problem. So even doe i know it's there, i don't know where it comes from, and besides that look how the font in there is kindof messed up for some mysterious reasons too. And on top of that that messiness of the font changes overtime when i move the mouse. So i am way too much confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `section` tag contains one closing `"` quote too much:

[image]

(directly before the closing ">" bracket.)

Delete that - maybe that's the cause.